# My template binding in polymerjs does not work?

Tags: html, templates, polymer

I have a dom element `<dom-module id="x-app">` and on this dome element I am loading 3 website pages. On the second webpage I use a polymer template, gallery template

```
<link rel="import" href="simple-gallery.html">
<dom-module id="x-app">
<neon-animatable> //Second page
  <paper-material class="vertical layout"> 
    <simple-gallery>
<img data-original="img01.bmp" data-index='l1' on-click="load_popup" src="img01.bmp"> 
<img data-original="img02.bmp" data-index='l2' on-click="load_popup" src="img02.bmp">
<img data-original="img03.bmp" data-index='l3' on-click="load_popup">
</simple-gallery>
<hr></hr>
</paper-material>
</neon-animatable>

<neon-animatable> //Third page
  <paper-material class="vertical layout">
    <simple-gallery>
<img data-original="img01.bmp" data-index='l1' on-click="load_popup" src="img01.bmp"> 
<img data-original="img02.bmp" data-index='l2' on-click="load_popup" src="img02.bmp">
<img data-original="img03.bmp" data-index='l3' on-click="load_popup">
</simple-gallery>
<hr></hr>
</paper-material>
</neon-animatable>
</dom-module>
```

and here is it my `simple-gallery` code

```
<dom-module id="simple-gallery" >
<script>
            HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
        (function() {
             var current_index = 0;
             var image_length = 0;

             Polymer({
                is: "simple-gallery",
                ready: function() {
                        var images = Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('img');
                        var container = this.$.links;

                        for (var img in images) {
                            images[img].addEventListener('click',this.load_popup);
                            container.appendChild(images[img]);
                        }
                },
                load_popup: function(e, detail, sender) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var links = document.getElementById('links');
                    image_length = links.getElementsByTagName('img').length;

                    var image_url = e.target.getAttribute('data-original');
                    var modalbody = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0];
                    var modal_img = modalbody.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
                    modal_img.setAttribute("src",image_url);
                    var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
                    modal.style.display = 'block';

                    current_index = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-index').replace("s",""));
                    return false;
                },
                next: function () {

                  current_index = current_index + 1;
                  if(current_index == (image_length + 1) ){
                      current_index = 1;
                  }
                  var current_image = document.querySelectorAll("[data-index='s"+current_index+"']");
                  image_url = current_image[0].getAttribute('data-original');
                  var modalbody = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0];
                  var modal_img = modalbody.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
                  modal_img.setAttribute("src",image_url);
                },
                prev: function () {
                  current_index = current_index - 1;
                  console.log("inside prev");
                  if(current_index == 0 ){
                      current_index = image_length;
                  }
                  var current_image = document.querySelectorAll("[data-index='s"+current_index+"']");
                  image_url = current_image[0].getAttribute('data-original');
                  var modalbody = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0];
                  var modal_img = modalbody.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
                  modal_img.setAttribute("src",image_url);
                },
                close: function () {
                  var modal = document.getElementsByClassName("modal")[0];
                  modal.style.display = "none";
                },

                });
        })();

            });
    </script>

    <template>

        <div id="gallery-panel" class="gallery-panel">
            <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
            <div class="slides">
                <div id="links" name="links"></div>
            </div>


            <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
            <div class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <a class="close"><button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" on-click="close" style="color: #f57c00;">Close</button></a>
                            <h2 class="modal-title">Title</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body next"><img class='modal-img'  /></div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <paper-material id="previous" type="button" class="style-scope x-app x-scope paper-button-0  pull-left prev" elevation="1" on-click="prev">Previous</paper-material>
                           <paper-material id="next" type="button" class="style-scope x-app x-scope paper-button-0 next" on-click="next">Next</paper-material>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

On the third page I load the same template. But when I click on the third page template image the image pop-ups on the second page and not on the third page where I make the call.

How to make the image popup in the page that has been called?

I tried making two separate templates but still the image pop ups on the second page.

Please help

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your problem. Would you mind if you can share the other parts of your code?

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal ok I will update my question now

Comment: @NeilJohnRamal done.. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always use `Polymer.dom` when doing DOM manipulations with Polymer. Avoid using regular DOM accessors (`document.querySelector`, `document.querySelectorAll`, `document.getElementById`, etc) as much as possible.**

Here's my solution. If you have any questions about my answer, feel free to PM me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-material/paper-material.html">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="x-app">
    <template>
      <neon-animatable>
        <paper-material class="vertical layout">
          <simple-gallery>
            <img data-original="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" data-index='1' src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports">
            <img data-original="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract" data-index='2' src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract">
            <img data-original="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" data-index='3' src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
          </simple-gallery>
          <hr></hr>
        </paper-material>
      </neon-animatable>

      <neon-animatable>
        <paper-material class="vertical layout">
          <simple-gallery>
            <img data-original="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports" data-index='1' src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports">
            <img data-original="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract" data-index='2' src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/abstract">
            <img data-original="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" data-index='3' src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/">
          </simple-gallery>
          <hr></hr>
        </paper-material>
      </neon-animatable>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <dom-module id="simple-gallery">
    <template>

      <div id="gallery-panel" class="gallery-panel">
        <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
        <div class="slides">
          <div id="links" name="links">
            <content select="img"></content>
          </div>
        </div>


        <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
        <div class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close">
                  <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" on-click="close" style="color: #f57c00;">Close</button>
                </a>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Title</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body next">
                <img class='modal-img' />
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <paper-material id="previous" type="button" class="style-scope x-app x-scope paper-button-0  pull-left prev" elevation="1" on-click="prev">Previous</paper-material>
                <paper-material id="next" type="button" class="style-scope x-app x-scope paper-button-0 next" on-click="next">Next</paper-material>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>

  <x-app></x-app>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-app'
    });

    Polymer({
      is: "simple-gallery",
      properties: {
        currentIndex: {
          type: Number,
          value: 0
        },
        imageLength: Number
      },
      ready: function() {
        var images = Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('img');
        var container = this.$.links;
        images.forEach(function(img) {
          img.addEventListener('click', this.load_popup.bind(this));
        }.bind(this));
      },
      load_popup: function(e, detail, sender) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var links = this.$.links;
        this.imageLength = Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('img').length;

        var image_url = e.target.dataset.original;
        var modal_img = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('img.modal-img');
        modal_img.setAttribute("src", image_url);
        var modal = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector(".modal");
        modal.style.display = 'block';

        this.currentIndex = parseInt(e.target.dataset.index);
      },
      next: function() {

        this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex + 1;
        if (this.currentIndex == (this.imageLength + 1)) {
          this.currentIndex = 1;
        }
        var current_image = Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('img')[this.currentIndex - 1];
        var image_url = current_image.dataset.original;
        var modal_img = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('img.modal-img');
        modal_img.setAttribute("src", image_url);
      },
      prev: function() {
        this.currentIndex = this.currentIndex - 1;
        if (this.currentIndex == 0) {
          this.currentIndex = this.imageLength;
        }
        var current_image = Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll('img')[this.currentIndex - 1];
        var image_url = current_image.dataset.original;
        var modal_img = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('img.modal-img');
        modal_img.setAttribute("src", image_url);
      },
      close: function() {
        var modal = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector(".modal");
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I will check it out now :)